# Getting key-value pairs from JSON array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hot to get in JavaScript key-value pairs if the JSON file looks like this:

```
 [[{"field":"name","message":"Insert name!"},{"field":"surname","message":"Inseerts     
 urname!"},{"field":"email","message":"Insert email"}]];
```

Current solution returns me one object like Object object Object object Object object and so on.

Code:

```
 var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
 var json_text = JSON.stringify(result, null, null);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: There is a problem with the JSON you provided, did you wrote it or just copy and paste it , because you are missing a quote right after 'Insert email'

Comment: I have copied it wrong, I have allready fix the question!

Comment: I mean I have fixed the question but still I don't have any solution for my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confusing the concepts. There is a difference between a STRING that contains JSON data, such as this:

```
var json = '[[{"field":"name","message":"Insert name!"},{"field":"surname","message":"Inseertssurname!"},{"field":"email","message":"Insert email"}]]';
```

and an OBJECT that contains JSON data, such as this:

```
var data = [[{"field":"name","message":"Insert name!"},{"field":"surname","message":"Inseertsurname!"},{"field":"email","message":"Insert email"}]];
```

The former you have to parse (for example with `JSON.parse` or `jQuery.parseJSON`) which turns it into the latter, which you can then access directly in your script (JSON = JavaScript Object Notation).

Your data is a double-nested list of objects and can be accessed as such:

```
console.log(data[0][1].field);
data[0].forEach(function (obj) { console.log(obj.field + ': ' + obj.message); });
```

(List are objects too (`typeof [] === 'object'`) but a special case, see the answer Igor already suggested).

If you are retrieving the data with a library, you often get your data as an object ready to access, if in doubt try:

```
typeof data // 'string' or 'object' ?
```